# StackOverflow tidy-up day!

Tags: discussion, badge-request, motivation, clean-up

For the last couple of days I've been digging deep in the **Unanswered Questions** tab and looking at all those questions that do have answers and no upvotes and upvoting if there is a correct answer.

What I'm proposing is a ***call to action*** to clean the Unanswered Questions and give proper credit to those who've actually took the time to answer. We could organize an all-day like Wordpress does. It would be fun to look at the figures pre and after cleanup. In the end making it a special day would be just a way of motivation on the community. Perhaps we could have a special - cleanup day - badge.

What do you think of the idea?

**Edit:** to better explain my proposal, as suggested, here go some links and more specificity into the pot.

**[Wordpress bug hunt day page](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Bug_Hunts)** - WP plans a specific day for bug-hunting. All days are good for bug-hunting, sure. But having a specific day and doing things together is part of the fun. A bit like running. I run weekly but it's more thrilling on 1/2-a-marathon organized days!

**[Typo3 bug day](http://typo3.org/development/bug-fixing/bug-day/)** - Same thing as above. They summarize it clearly with the line: *The motivation for having a Bug Day is to foster community outreach and growth.*

**How would credit be given?**

A bit like the *"Beta"* badge, SO team could create one that would be given to all users who, on the day xx, voted (up or down), edited, commented and so forth all questions older than yy amount of days sitting on the Unanswered pool.

**How could we prevent overlaping work?**

A good things about SO is that this has been taken care from the start up. If an answers gets two upvotes it gets two upvotes - there is really no more overlapping that on the [new-questions-fastest-gun-in-the-west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) pool.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! You've got to forgive me for my somewhat limited English being myself Portuguese. I do try to spell check it all, but somethings just go under the hood.

Answer (score 9):

I think every day should be clean-up day. We want people to do this sort of thing all the time, which is why we have a [badge for voting](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/32/civic-duty).

Of course, you should only upvote an answer if it's *correct*, not just to remove the question from the Unanswered list.

Comment: Oh; guess I better retract all those upvotes then...

Comment: Evidently, but we have roughly 5900 questions unanswered and rising. I was clearly leaning on the motivation and party-ish aspect of having special days! :)

Answer (score 3):

I think a link to your example of what Wordpress does might help explain the community aspect of your proposal. Otherwise it sounds a little like a day when some people will spend more time and effort on StackOverflow than others and it's not clear to me how you get counted as having participated, or how the workload gets distributed and un-duplicated.

Answer (score 3):

While I like the spirit of the idea …

> A bit like the "Beta" badge, SO team could create one that would be given to all users who, on the day xx, voted (up or down), edited, commented and so forth all questions older than yy amount of days sitting on the Unanswered pool.

This would create a bit of a perverse incentive to vote up unanswered questions, just to get the badge.

Plus, we already have Civic Duty, and another badge related to voting that I haven't rolled out yet.

Comment: Are you talking about Sportsmanship?

Comment: @random: Ooooh, I hope so! ;)

Comment: Woww! A new badge coming up! ;) Wanna see that. Thanks for the answer!