# Idea: regular voter badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, voting

Should we add a new badge (silver):

**Regular voter**: Voted at least once every week for 20 weeks in a row.

This helps make sure people vote regularly and is somewhat more powerful than the Civic Duty badge.

Comment: A **Metamucil** badge?

Comment: Exactly once, or at least once?

Comment: at least once, amended, thx

Comment: **Once** every week? How about once every ten minutes? Sounds way more realistic to me.

Comment: Democrat? Too localized

Comment: @Manni: some of us **do not** answer while we sleep.

Comment: @Manni: some of us **do** sleep.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, but then people will ask for a Republican badge, which will lead to the inevitable Ron Paul badge...

Comment: At least it could be a change we can all believe in.

Comment: And what about for those of us that aren't happy with any of them at the moment? We could call it the Congress badge if you only vote, but don't actually answer anyone's problems.

Comment: +1000 to AnonJr

Comment: Speaking of which, where is my Ron Paul badge? We need a badge for the purists here.

Comment: Renamed suggestion to regular voter, which is a much better subject to votes. bring on the poo jokes.

Comment: There's already a Republican badge... it's called "Critic". ;)

Comment: Ron Paul badge? Where can I get one?

Answer (score 3):

Another vote related badge is [set to come rolling out of the SO factory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28581/stackoverflow-tidy-up-day/28788#28788) in the who knows when future:

> [image: Jeff Atwood]
>    Plus, we already have Civic Duty, and another badge related to voting that I haven't rolled out yet.

Comment: I'm guessing it's coming in six to eight weeks?

Answer (score 3):

That badge should be reserved for users who log in and vote under multiple accounts on the same day.

Comment: this so needs multiple upvotes!

Comment: Wouldn't that be the Chicago badge?  It should also be awarded for any posthumous voting.

Comment: I believe that badge would be called "Chadmaster"